# HomeController (String[]) Method is not Valid in Given Context (ASP.Net MVC C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, methods

I'm currently building a program that processes tickets (agile) in different stages. For some reason I'm having a hard time resolving an error with my home controller and model references. I am being told that model.DueFilter = **Filter**.DueFilterValue is a method (Filter) which is not valid in the given context.

Below is my Home Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private TicketContext context;

    public HomeController(TicketContext ctx) => context = ctx;

    public IActionResult Index(string ID)
    {
        AgileViewModel model = new AgileViewModel();

        var filter = new Filter(ID);
        model.Filter = new Filter(ID);
        model.Sprints = context.Sprints.ToList();
        model.TicketStatuses = context.TicketStatuses.ToList();
        model.DueFilter = Filter.DueFilterValue;

        IQueryable<Ticket> query = context.Tickets.Include(t => t.Sprint).Include(t => t.TicketStatus);

        if (filter.HasSprint)
        {
            query = query.Where(t => t.SprintID == filter.SprintID);
        }

        if (filter.HasTicketStatus)
        {
            query = query.Where(t => t.TicketStatusID == filter.TicketStatusID);
        }

        if (filter.HasDue)
        {
            var currentDate = DateTime.Today;

            if (filter.isPast)
                query = query.Where(t => t.Deadline < currentDate);
            else if (filter.isFuture)
                query = query.Where(t => t.Deadline > currentDate);
            else if (filter.isToday)
                query = query.Where(t => t.Deadline == currentDate);
        }

        var tasks = query.OrderBy(t => t.Deadline).ToList();

        model.Tasks = tasks;

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Here is my `Filter` model:

```
public class Filter
{
    public Filter(string filterstring)
    {
        FilterString = filterstring ?? "all-all-all";
        string[] filter = FilterString.Split('-');
        SprintID = filter[0];
        Due = filter[1];
        TicketStatusID = filter[2];
    }

    public string FilterString { get; }
    public string SprintID { get; }
    public string Due { get; }
    public string TicketStatusID { get; }

    public bool HasSprint => SprintID.ToLower() != "all";
    public bool HasDue => Due.ToLower() != "all";
    public bool HasTicketStatus => TicketStatusID.ToLower() != "all";

    public static Dictionary<string, string> DueFilterValue =>
        new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"future", "Future" },
            {"past", "Past" },
            {"today", "Today" }
        };
    public bool isPast => Due.ToLower() == "past";
    public bool isFuture => Due.ToLower() == "future";
    public bool isToday => Due.ToLower() == "today";
}
```

Add lastly my ModelView:

```
public class AgileViewModel
{
    public AgileViewModel()
    {
        CurrentTask = new Ticket();
    }

    public Filter Filter { get; set; }

    public List<TicketStatus> TicketStatuses { get; set; }

    public List<Sprint> Sprints { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, string> DueFilter { get; set; }

    public List<Ticket> Tasks { get; set; }

    public Ticket CurrentTask { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Which.NET version are you targeting? And which Visual Studio version?

Comment: .Net 3.0 on Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Strange... I made it work in [fiddler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/m4ISKb)

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is on my end then- I've been playing around with still no resolution

Comment: Do you get a compiler error? If so, where? On `model.DueFilter = Filter.DueFilterValue`?